PHP PDO Query is not returning any results despite SQL query running correctly in MySQL Workbench
I am working on some PHP code where I take a comma seperated string from a user table, and seperate it into a comma seperated string to be inserted into another SQL query to pull the comma seperated values as the primary keys in another table. The issue is starting on line 29, the constructed query isn't returning any results when I set it up with PDO. The constructed query returns the expected results fine when I run it directly in MySQL workbench, but not in the PHP file. My code is below, the issue appears to be happening somewhere in the last 10 lines, I tried to echo out the query results but it returns 0 results. I plan on using the query results to populate a select element dynamically with fields from the database.
<?php
                    require_once "include/dbh.inc.php";
                    $user_id = 21; //will be replaced with user ID from session variable in production
                    $sql = "SELECT linked_properties FROM ent_users WHERE ent_user_id=:user_id;";
                    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $result->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id);
                    $result->execute();
                    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($row);
                    echo "</pre>";

                    $linked_prop = $row['linked_properties'];
                    $linked_prop_arr = explode(",",$linked_prop);

                    $query_bgn = "SELECT property_id, prop_dba_name FROM property_data WHERE property_id IN ( ";
                    $query_end = ");";

                    $temp = NULL;
                    foreach($linked_prop_arr as $prop_name) {
                        $temp .= " ". "'" . $prop_name . "'" . " " . ",";
                    }

                    $temp = rtrim($temp, ',');
                    echo $temp . '<br>';
                    echo $query_bgn . $temp . $query_end;

                    $sql_prop = "SELECT property_id, prop_dba_name FROM property_data WHERE property_id IN (:prop_list);";
                    $result_prop = $pdo->prepare($sql_prop);
                    $result_prop->bindParam(":prop_list", $temp);
                    $row_result = $result_prop->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    print_r($row_result);
                    
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($row_result);
                    echo "</pre>";

                    ?>


The code that is above the below code appears to be functioning correctly, the issue starts at line 29. I was expecting the following code to return an array of 7 results from the SQL query, but no results are returned. The end result that I am working towards is to use the "property_id" as the value in a select element and the "prop_dba_name" field as the name of the select element field.

                    $sql_prop = "SELECT property_id, prop_dba_name FROM property_data WHERE property_id IN (:prop_list);";
                    $result_prop = $pdo->prepare($sql_prop);
                    $result_prop->bindParam(":prop_list", $temp);
                    $row_result = $result_prop->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    print_r($row_result);
                    
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($row_result);
                    echo "</pre>";


See this: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in
